# Swift error: Cannot assign to immutable value

Tags: macos, swift, immutability

I got the error above for this code snippet:

```
func store(name: String, inout array: [AnyObject]) {

    for object in array {

        if object is [AnyObject] {

            store(name, &object)
            return
        }
    }
    array.append(name)
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the item `object` extracted with `for` is immutable. You should iterate `indices` of the array instead.

And, the item is `AnyObject` you cannot pass it to `inout array: [AnyObject]` parameter without casting. In this case, you should cast it to  mutable `[AnyObject]` and then *reassign* it:

```
func store(name: String, inout array: [AnyObject]) {
    for i in indices(array) {
        if var subarray = array[i] as? [AnyObject] {
            store(name, &subarray)
            array[i] = subarray // This converts `subarray:[AnyObject]` to `NSArray`
            return
        }
    }
    array.append(name)
}

var a:[AnyObject] = [1,2,3,4,[1,2,3],4,5]
store("foo", &a) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, "foo"], 4, 5]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I do not understand it completely, but it works ;-)