# How to mutate variable in array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to receive mutable variable from my array, but something goes wrong. Question in code.

```
var baloonsArray = NSMutableArray()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        var baloon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "baloon") //"Variable "baloon" was never mutated; consider changing to "let" constant"
        baloon.xScale = 0.1
        baloon.yScale = 0.1

        ballonsArray.addObject(baloon)
        addChild(baloon)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        for var baloon in baloonsArray {
            baloon.xScale = 0.2 //Here xcode telling me: "Cannot assign to property: "ballon" is immutable". But i declared him as var. With Objective-C there was no problems. What should i do? 

        }
    }
}
```

When Im trying to change baloon xScale in touchesBegan function xcode telling me: "Cannot assign to property: "ballon" is immutable". But i declared him as var. With Objective-C there was no problems. What should i do?

Comment: Please don't ask your question *in the code* as it's hard to see it.

Comment: please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674399/swift-error-cannot-assign-to-immutable-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your use of NSMutableArray. To Swift, it is opaque. That is, Swift doesn't know what is in it. But Swift has strict typing. So it doesn't know what properties its elements have, and it isn't going to let you assign to a property it doesn't understand. So if you really want to use NSMutableArray, you must *cast* its elements when you fetch them, so Swift knows what they are:

```
for baloon in baloonsArray {
    let baloonsprite = baloon as! SKSpriteNode
    baloonsprite.xScale = 0.2
}
```

That works. However, it would be better not to use NSMutableArray in the first place. Instead, declare `baloonsArray` as a mutable *Swift* array:

```
var baloonsArray = [SKSpriteNode]()
```

That takes care of the problem in a much neater way. Now Swift knows what is in this array - it is SKSpriteNode objects. And Swift knows that it is okay to assign to an SKSpriteNode's `xScale`.

You need to get used to Swift's strict typing, including the fact that the elements of an array are typed.

Comment: Ops... I didn't see the update in your answer. I repeated the same concept in my own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

### Point 1

In the following code you are defining a variable `balloon`.

This variable exists until it goes out of scope at the end of the method, just an instant before the `}`.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    var balloon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "baloon") //"Variable "baloon" was never mutated; consider changing to "let" constant"
    balloon.xScale = 0.1
    balloon.yScale = 0.1

    ballonsArray.addObject(balloon)
    addChild(balloon)
}
```

Now, this variable refers an object of type `SKSpriteNode`. This means that the variable is a `pointer`, more specifically it contains a number that is the address of the sprite inside the heap.

If you change some property of the sprite you are **not** changing the variable, infact the variable `balloon` still contains the address of the sprite into the heap. So you are not mutating it.

The only way to mutate the variable `balloon` is assigning it to another `SKSpriteNode`. You are not doing it so the warning correct.

### Point 2

The matt's answer is totally correct.

You could also consider not to use `NSMutableArray`. The Swift native array is much better and does support generics. So you can avoid a cast.

```
class Scene : SKScene {

    var ballonsArray = [SKSpriteNode]()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let balloon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "baloon")
        balloon.xScale = 0.1
        balloon.yScale = 0.1
        ballonsArray.append(balloon)
        addChild(balloon)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        ballonsArray.map { $0.xScale = 0.2 }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could it be because your Point 1 is totally bogus?

Comment: @matt: The OP reported a `warning` and an `error` from the compiler: they are added as comments in the block of code of the question. I tried to answer both. I have read lots of your answers matt and I totally respect your knowledge about Swift, but now I don't understand where I am wrong.